# Is it possible to construct a 1-D linear differential operator with given spectrum $0\leq\lambda_0\leq \lambda_1\leq\dots\leq\lambda_n\le\dots$?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-operators

Suppose one is given with a sequence $S$ of non-negative real numbers $0\leq\lambda_0\leq \lambda_1\leq\dots\leq \lambda_n\leq\dots$. Under what conditions on $S$, is it possible to construct a Linear differential operator $D$ on the space of square integrable functions on the real line, such that the eigenvalue spectrum of $D$ is given by $S$ ? Is there any way to explicitly construct such an operator ?